# Getting a runtime error in Level Order Traversal in Binary Tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

### *Getting a runtime error,cant find where am i wrong*

### I think there is some memory related problem but not able to trace it

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* leftchild;
    struct node* rightchild;
};
```

### For new node Creation

```
struct node* newnode(int data)
{
    struct node* node=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data=data;
    node->leftchild=NULL;
    node->rightchild=NULL;
    return node;
 }
```

### Height of tree

```
int height(struct node* root)
{
    int lheight,rheight;
    if(root==NULL)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        lheight=height(root->leftchild);
        rheight=height(root->rightchild);
    }
    if(lheight>rheight)
        return lheight+1;
    else 
        return rheight+1;
}
```

### Recurrsive Function to print nodes

```
void printlevelorder(struct node* root,int current,int level)
{
    if(current==level)
    {
        printf("%d ",root->data);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printlevelorder(root->leftchild,current+1,level);
        printlevelorder(root->rightchild,current+1,level);
    }

 }
```

### Function to traverese each level

```
void levelorder(struct node* root)
{
    int h,i;
    h= height(root);
    if(h!=0){
        for(i=1;i<=h;i++)
        {
            printlevelorder(root,1,i);
        }
    }
    else 
        printf("Tree not exist\n");
}
```

### Driver Program to test the functionality

```
int main()
{
    struct node* root=newnode(1);
    root->leftchild=newnode(2);
    root->rightchild=newnode(7);
    root->leftchild->leftchild=newnode(3);
    root->leftchild->rightchild=newnode(6);
    root->leftchild->leftchild->leftchild=newnode(4);
    root->leftchild->leftchild->leftchild->rightchild=newnode(5);
    root->rightchild->leftchild=newnode(9);
    root->rightchild->rightchild=newnode(8);
    levelorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger before?  If not, this would be a great place to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stop recursively calling your `printlevelorder` function when `current` is the maximum height of your tree (5 in your case). Since the height of `root`'s right subtree is less than 5, you will get a segmentation fault when you traverse that subtree when `current` is large enough. A better solution will be to stop the recursive calls when you encounter a `NULL` node rather than checking when `current` reaches 5.

Answer (score 0):

The function `printlevelorder` doesn't check if the pointer `root` is null.

Add the check for NULL as the first statement in the function:

```
if( !root )
{
    return;
}
```

to stop the recursion when the parts of the tree aren't as deep as the argument `level` assumes they are.

Comment: Thanks that really helps me alot

Answer (score 0):

```
void printLevelOrder(struct node* root)
{
    int h, i;
    h = height(root);

    for (i=1; i<=h; i++)
        levelorder(root, i);
}

/* Print nodes at a given level */
void levelorder(struct node* root, int level)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    if (level == 1)
        printf("%d ", root->data);
    else if (level > 1)
    {
        printGivenLevel(root->left, level-1);
        printGivenLevel(root->right, level-1);
    }
}
```